# VNC Server failed to start on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, vnc

VNC Server suddenly stopped working on my VM after working fine without any issues. I cannot seem to start the VNC service.

This is the output for the status of the VNC service

```
    systemctl -l status vncserver@:1.service
● vncserver@:1.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:1.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: resources) since Mon 2017-07-31 09:31:48 UTC; 4h 44min ago
  Process: 11659 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/runuser -l user -c /usr/bin/vncserver %i -geometry 1280x1024 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11648 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || : (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 31 09:31:45 hname systemd[1]: Starting Remote desktop service (VNC)...
Jul 31 09:31:48 hname systemd[1]: PID file /home/user/.vnc/reggie:1.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Jul 31 09:31:48 hname systemd[1]: Failed to start Remote desktop service (VNC).
Jul 31 09:31:48 hname systemd[1]: Unit vncserver@:1.service entered failed state.
Jul 31 09:31:48 hname systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service failed.
```

Does anyone have any tips on how to get this working? I have double checked the location and contents of my configuration file.

Comment: did you get this sorted out? (am seeing the same "suddenly")